# How can I shrink .MKV files?

Tags: software-recommendation, file-size, mkv

I am using Handbrake to rip a DVD to a MKV. The filesize for a ~5GB .VOB rip is a nearly 2GB .MKV.

Is there a program in Ubuntu that shrinks MKV's? I looked around and found a lot of Windows programs, but none that work well in Wine. I was thinking about shrinking it to a 300-400MB file (Like most MKV rips), but I don't know how to shrink it in Ubuntu. Any ideas?

Comment: Most mkv rips actually are usually around 700 MB (as per the new "Scene" guidelines) or 1.2 GB. Just saying.

Comment: Got ya. Ugh, I just need a way to get out of this 2GB range for the rip. Any ideas?

Comment: Lower the bitrate. Depending on your video duration you can calculate it by hand to fit 300 MB

Comment: I'll give it a shot and let you know if it works. (So I know for reference, could you tell me what bitrate actually entitles? I'm a bit of a noob at that stuff :P)

Comment: I couldn't know when I don't know the duration. Better search for bitrate calculator, so you can do it yourself in future ^_^

Comment: .facepalm. :P got ya. Do me a favor, and put your comment about changing the bitrate as an answer for me, so that if it works, I can accept your answer and get you some reputation :)

Comment: From http://www.videohelp.com/glossary?B#Bitrate

Bitrate
Bitrate or Bit Rate is the average number of bits that one second of video or audio data will consume. Higher bitrate means bigger file size and generally better video or audio quality while lower bitrate means lower file size but worse video or audio quality. Some bitrate examples in common video and audio files: 
MP3 about 128 kbps (kilobits per second) 
VCD about 1374 kbps 
DVD about 4500 kbps 
DV about 25 Mbps (megabits per second).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this:

[image]

so for your 400MB example, if the duration is 1 hour (3600 seconds):

```
x = 400MB*8192/3600 = 910 Kbps
```

Then you subtract 128Kbs for standard 128 Kbps audio (MP3/OGG/AAC whatever) and you are left with ~800 Kbps for your (hopefully x264) video

Comment: Excellent answer! Did exactly what I needed! Thank you so incredibly much!!

Comment: Broken image in this answer, please update.

Comment: Is the image there now the correct one? It doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: The provided answer is to change the bitrate when ripping the DVD, according to that formula.